# How to make an Inner Join in django without foreign key?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

how to make statement of join on in django 1.11,
i want to create this statement :

```
select t1.name ,t2.str, t2.num
from table_1 as t1
join table_2 as t2 on t2.product_id = t1.id and t2.section_num = 2;

the models:


class t1(UTModelTS):
    alt_keys = product_alt_keys
    name = utCharField()
    ...

class t2(UTModelTS):
    alt_keys= [('pr_id', 'section')]    
    str = utCharField()
    num = models.IntegerField()

    ...
```

i tried

```
 t1 = t1.objects.filter(**params).exclude(**exclude)
 t1 = t1.select_related('t2')
`
```

but this make no sense since acoridng to django doc :
**select_related
Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships...**
from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/ .

Comment: Could you add your models there for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an effective / elegant way unfortunately.

although you can use `.raw()/RawSQL()` method for this exact thing. Even if it could it probably would be a lot slower than raw SQL.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `on` statement. **Django's** ORM will performs inner join for you automatically.

## Imagine this is our models. User Table and Post table.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(to='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # this is FK field to users
```

## Usage

```
qs = Post.objects.select_related('user') # This will performs SQL INNER JOIN.
print(qs.query) # use query attribute to show what query is performed.
```

This will be generated SQL query

```sql
SELECT "myapp_post"."id", "myapp_post"."title", "myapp_post"."text", "myapp_post"."user_id", "myapp_user"."id", "myapp_user"."name", "myapp_user"."surname" FROM "myapp_post" INNER JOIN "myapp_user" ON ("myapp_post"."user_id" = "myapp_user"."id")
```

Look your models,,,

```
class t1(UTModelTS):
    alt_keys = product_alt_keys
    name = utCharField()
    t2 = models.ForeignKey(to='t2', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class t2(UTModelTS):
    alt_keys= [('pr_id', 'section')]    
    str = utCharField()
    num = models.IntegerField()
```

add t2 FK to your t1 Model.

Querying

```
qs = t1.objects.select_related('t2')
```

## OR

```
qs = t1.objects.select_related('t2').filter(**lookup_kwargs).
```

`select_related()` returns `QuerySet` object, you can use `QuerySet` methods after `select_related()`.

Comment: Where is ForeignKey() fields in your models ?

Comment: the field from t2 is not ForeignKeyto t1

Comment: maybe with .extra ?

Comment: You also can use .extra(), because .extra() is QuerySet method also. but to perform joins select_related().

Comment: i got Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'str' into field. Choices are: annotation, attribute1n, attribute1s, attribute2n,.. al the rest of fields of t1 when tired qs = t1.objects.select_related('t2').filter(**lookup_kwargs).

Comment: what is lookup_kwargs in your case ?

Comment: qs = t1.objects.select_related('t2').filter(**{'name':  'something'}).

Comment: i can't use objects i get : Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'
becase i am already has prevois qyerSet that i want to extend

Comment: objects is Model attribute/and not QuerySet which is instance of Manager class as usual. Read documentation and understand basics. Good luck.

Comment: i want to join querySet is this not possible in django ?

Comment: I think you did not read my answer. .select_related() is for this purposes.